# Should we memoize closures?

Tags: flutter

I am using the `functional_widget` package together with `flutter_hooks`. I need to create closures for event handlers and I am wondering what is the proper way:

```
@hwidget
Widget foo1() {
  final state = useState(0);
  final onPressed = () {
    state.value++;
  };
  return RaisedButton(onPressed: onPressed);
}
```

vs

```
@hwidget
Widget foo2() {
  final state = useState(0);
  final onPressed = useMemoized(() => () {
        state.value++;
      });
  return RaisedButton(onPressed: onPressed);
}
```

Am I saving cost or making it worse by using `useMemomized`? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, but it is not necessary.

On the other hand, if you do so, it is critical to correctly specify keys:

```dart
final state = useState(0);
final cb = useMemoized(() => () {
  state.value++;
}, [state]);
```

Failing to do so may cause your closure to point to the previous parameters instead of the new ones.

Comment: With `useState` it should be fine, but I was just trapped by closing over a local variable and `useMemoized`. But, which one is faster?

Comment: UseState is likely to be changed to be immutable. Which will break your code if you don't use key

Comment: Perf wise, it depends. In that specific case it's probably useless. But it could be useful to memoiize the entire RaisedButton.